# Corny - rebus puzzle

Tags: rebus

This is yet another rebus puzzle

[image: REBUS]

What does it mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1 followed by corn - it must be

> a unicorn

Answer (score 5):

> Unicorn. But it can also be A-maze = Amaze

Comment: (Maize and maze are different things.)