# What is this rebus or phrase saying?

Tags: rebus

The rebus is in the image below. Hope you will find it out.

[image]

<sub>[Puzzle source](https://www.queryhome.com/puzzle/24359/what-is-this-rebus-or-phrase-saying) (link contains solution).</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is

> LOG CABIN

because the picture shows

> a **cab** (taxi) **in** a **log**.

Comment: That's insanely quick. :o

Comment: @Sid Pfft. Over a minute? I've [done better](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/9383/5373) :-)

Comment: [Deusovi has you beat :)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/51082/30633)